# Does an electric motor benefit by being given a rest?

Tags: motor, electric-machine

Will the following two scenarios give different results on the wear/safety of a consumer-grade electric motor:

- A: Run motor for 12 hours/day for 20 days
- B: Run motor for 24 hours/day for 10 days

(In each case the motor runs for 240 hours)

Comment: Probably neither.  Load and temperature play a more significant factor. You also need to be more specific regarding the motor. Eg for an induction motor, the main failure is mechanical as there’s two bearings. Load affects the temperature  which affects the bearing lubrication. Lubrication affects the bearing friction and so on.

Comment: One might argue the reverse. That the motor which runs continuously avoids the stressful startup, while the motor which started 20 times will have more "wear". But here I am playing devil's advocate, and don't have any data.

Comment: Depends are the best answer for wear.  Stresses and temperatures that the motor sees through these scenarios would likely be more important than the durations - it's about the stress and thermal cycles rather than the durations.  If I have a thin bar of metal, I may be able to break it in two pieces with a single hit if I hit hard enough.  I may also break it by repeatedly bending and unbending it some distance.  I however cannot break (not quickly anyway) it by bending it and leaving it in that bent state.

Comment: The only way I can see a motor benefit from a rest is if the motor's thermal equilibrium results in a temperature beyond what it can tolerate and it's thermal capacity is such it hasn't reached that equilibrium during the run time. But for that to be the case when the run time is a day, let alone 10 or 20 days would running a very MASSIVE MASSIVE motor, or a normal motor under very, very specific conditions.

Comment: There's too many variables in the question.  For most reasonable schemes, it'll be better to run continually, because thermal cycling tends to do Bad Things to motors.  Mostly -- it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the following two scenarios give **different** results on the
> wear/safety of a consumer-grade electric motor:

Yes, but what difference there will be is dependent on too many variables to say which of your two scenarios will result in more or less 'wear/safety', or whether the difference will be significant. For example:-

- A has 20 times more starts and stops than B, which will increase brush wear and commutator erosion in a brushed motor. But 20 starts and stops isn't many, so the difference may not be significant.
- B runs the motor for 20 times as long without a cool-down period. Depending on the time taken to reach equilibrium temperature, B could expose the motor to higher temperatures for longer, which may degrade various parts (insulation, bearings, magnets...) more.
- On the other hand, running at a constant temperature reduces stresses caused by temperature changes, and if the motor is operated in a high humidity environment then running continuously may protect it from corrosion and insulation breakdown.